Deal with discontinuity in double integrals
Let $f(x,y)= \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2}$. Consider
$$ \int_D f(x,y)$$
with $D=\{ (x,y): 0\leq y\leq x, x^2+y^2\leq 1 \}$
The function is unbounded in $D$, due to the denominator. I checked that cannot be extended with continuity. So I have an improper double integral. How can I deal with it? Are change of variables forbidden, since the function is unbounded? Do I need to work in cartesian coordinares?

It seems like you have $0\le y\le x$ that gives you $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2}\le \frac{2x^2}{x^2}$...

Hint: Use polar coordinates.

You can use variables substitution when, for example, we are dealing with a one-to-one correspondence, the functions of which are continuously differentiable and the Jacobian does not vanish.

Just because integrands are unbounded does not mean they don't converge. But also in this case the integrand is not unbounded as @abiessu pointed out.

$f$ is obviously not well-defined at $(0,0)$, and we can show that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$$ does not exist for any path in $D$, since if $y = kx$ for some $k \in [0,1]$, we have for $x > 0$
$$f(x,kx) = \frac{x^2 + (kx)^2}{x^2} = 1 + k^2,$$ hence
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x,kx) = 1 + k^2.$$
However, that is not to say that $f$ is unbounded in $D$:  indeed, as observed in the comments, for any $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ in $D$, we have
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2} \le \frac{x^2 + x^2}{x^2} = 2$$
and $$f(x,y) \ge \frac{x^2 + 0^2}{x^2} = 1.$$
So $f$ is bounded everywhere in $D$ except at $(0,0)$ where it is not well-defined, consequently its integral over $D$ does exist and must be finite.
Because $f$ is constant on rays from the origin, it is natural to choose a Cartesian-to-polar transformation:  for $(x,y) \in D \setminus (0,0)$
$$(x,y) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$$
yields
$$f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) = 1 + \tan^2 \theta = \sec^2 \theta.$$
again confirming that $f$ is a constant function of $r$.  So we have
$$\iint_D f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_{r=0}^1 \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/4} (\sec^2 \theta) \, r \, dr \, d\theta$$
and the rest of the computation is straightforward.

Question about the statement 'its bounded everywhere in D except at zero where is not well defines, this the integral must exist and be finite'. Is this really true? What are the hyoothesis you are actually using? There are functional bounded in an interval that are not integrable. Are you using that the function is continuos in its domain?
